# c# запись в базу данных изменение textbox textchanged

Tags: c#

приложение winforms, с помощью фреймворка aforge с камеры считывается QR code, содержимое QR code записывается в textbox, теперь мне нужно каждое значение txtbox автоматический без button_click нужно записать в базу данных, скажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: Одновременно заносите данные и в текстбокс и в базу, что именно не получается? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: _содержимое QR code записывается в textbox_ - вот в этом месте записывайте в БД. Где-то в коде у вас примерно следующее: `textBox.Text = qrCode;`. Добавьте следом что-то вроде `SaveToDB(qrCode);`